# How to fix data duplicating issue when i try to submit a form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a serious issue.

When I submit a form a second time, with new data, then all other data goes duplicate with the last submission's data. Also, when I update any one of the columns it goes all the column data duplicate.

#### Html Form

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
    <input class="inputs" type="hidden" required id="id" name="id" placeholder="*Code...">
    <input class="inputs" type="number" required id="code" name="code" placeholder="*Code...">
    <input class="inputs" type="text" required id="product" name="products" placeholder="*Products...">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Suppliers..." name="supplier" id="supplier" class="inputs">
    <input class="inputs" type="number" required id="price" name="price" placeholder="*Price...">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SubmitForm();" value="send"> Save </button>
</form>
```

#### Search.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $response = array();
    if (isset($_GET['scode'])){
        //vul hier je database gebuikersnaam en ww in
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "waqar");

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $qry = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE code = '".$_GET['scode']."' ";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);  //mysql_query($qry);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
            array_push($response, $row);
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
    } 
?>
```

#### Submit.php

```
<?php
    // Establishing connection with server by passing "server_name", "user_id", "password".
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    // Selecting Database by passing "database_name" and above connection variable.
    $db = mysql_select_db("waqar", $connection);
    $scode = $_POST['code']; // Fetching Values from URL
    $sproduct = $_POST['products'];
    $sprice = $_POST['price'];
    $ssupplier = $_POST['supplier'];
    //echo $semail;

    $query = mysql_query("update products set products='$sproduct', price='$sprice', supplier='$ssupplier'"); //Insert query
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (code,products,price,supplier) values('$scode', '$sproduct', '$sprice', '$ssupplier') on duplicate KEY UPDATE 
      code='$scode', products='$sproduct', price='$sprice', supplier='$ssupplier'");

    if($query){
        echo "Data Submitted succesfully";
    }

    mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed.
?>
```

I want to know why that data is duplicating after submission. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `SubmitForm()` do?

Comment: You first update, which adds records, then insert, which adds records. hence the duplication.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: **WHY** does one script use `MYSQLI_` and the other use the **dead** `MYSQL_` API

Comment: @GavinSimpson ___Small Note___ Update does not ADD rows, it change/amends them

Comment: afaik @RiggsFolly it will add records if they don't exist

Comment: formatted code and question

Answer (score -1):

You are both updating and inserting your records. Also, why are you using `MySQL` and `MySqli` in two different forms? Do not use MySQL_connect.

```
$query = mysql_query("update products set products='$sproduct', price='$sprice', supplier='$ssupplier'"); //Insert query
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (code,products,price,supplier) values('$scode', '$sproduct', '$sprice', '$ssupplier') on duplicate KEY UPDATE 
code='$scode', products='$sproduct', price='$sprice', supplier='$ssupplier'");
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Please dont encourage the use of the deprecated (for year) and ___removed forever in PHP7+___ `mysql_` API

Comment: I'm not encouraging anything. Did you even read my post? @RiggsFolly

Comment: I'm not going to rewrite his code for him, he asked why there were duplications and I showed him where they were happening. @RiggsFolly